# System.UriFormatException is gone in WinRT, but Uri is not

Tags: windows-8

Trying to build a catch mechanism around the Uri type in WinRT.

So if the Uri is invalid I want to catch the UriFormatException of that type, but it seems it is not included in the WinRT .NET profile.

I haven't reflector'ed it.

Clues ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch FormatException now.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx